# Serve HTML Files in Sinatra From S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ember.js, amazon-s3, sinatra

I've looked over several SO questions that are somewhat similar to mine but haven't found a great implementation yet (here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295178/serve-html-files-stored-on-s3-on-a-rack-app) for example).

Right now we have an Ember app being hosted in S3 and we run a simple grunt task whenever we want to update what's in S3.  That works fine, everything gets pushed.

Now we want to use Sinatra to basically server this up.

What I'd like to do is something like

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/*' do
  render 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/index.html'
end
```

That way any request that comes in just defaults to the root and loads the ember app.

We're storing the Ember app in S3, we think it's the best/safest deployment we've found so far and this implementation would be fine but I can't get sinatra to actually load this.  I thought about getting the file, writing it to `public/index.html` (see link above) and then rendering that but it's overkill for what we need.

Open to other ideas but would like to go down this path if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by doing this:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'httparty'

get '/*' do
  url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/index.html'
  resp = HTTParty.get(url)
  resp.body
end
```